# How to get Ad Domain name in my forest

Tags: active-directory, powershell, domain

I have a big forest with many AD Domain, and frequently add new domains.
I need a list of these Ad Domain to query each DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function list your Active Directory Domain avaible in the forest (include the current domain => $Forest.Domains.name)

```
function get-AdInside () {
    $MainForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
    $ForestTrusts = $MainForest.GetAllTrustRelationships()
    $ADs = @($MainForest.Domains.name)
    $ADs += $ForestTrusts.TargetName
    return $ADs
}
```

tested with current domain 2008-2008r2-2012+

Comment: How about `(Get-ADForest).Domains`?

Answer (score 1):

`GetAllTrustRelationships()` is not a very failsafe way to enumerate all domains in the forest, and may include other forests/domains as well.

Grab the `Domains` references from the Forest object instead:

```
function Get-ADInside
{
    $Forest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
    $Domains = $Forest.Domains
    $Domains |Select -ExpandProperty Name
}
```

Comment: this code only include the current domain, not other in the current forest.